# Need what the final answer is

Tags: calculus

How do I integrate:
 $\int \frac{1}{(1+x\tan x)^2}dx$

Tried the following: substituting $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and got stuck
Next tried $\tan x = \frac{1}{\cot x}$ ,took LCM and did substitution.
 Don't know the final answer is correct or not

Comment: My final is 1/(x+cotx). Is this correct

Comment: $$\int \frac{1}{(1+x\tan x)^2}dx =\dfrac{\tan x}{x\tan x+1}+Cst $$ and Substitute $$ \tan x = \dfrac{1}{\cot x}$$

Answer (score 0):

your answer is correct

$$\int \frac{1}{(1+x\tan x)^2}dx =\dfrac{\tan x}{x\tan x+1}+Cst $$ and Substitute $$ \tan x = \dfrac{1}{\cot x}$$

\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{(1+x\tan x)^2}dx&=\dfrac{\tan x}{x\tan x+1}+Cst\\
&=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{\cot x}}{x\dfrac{1}{\cot x}+1}+Cst \\
&=\dfrac{1}{x+\cot x}+Cst \\
\end{align}